# What means it in the interest of science?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

> In the interests of science, can we get a couple non-mods to try an experiment? On meta, somebody ask a test question, somebody else answer, we DV the answer, asker accepts, and we get three high-rep users to try to delete. Main should work the same as meta on this.

Here's the question. Now it just needs the answers.

How much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to **[zot](http://www.henriettesherbal.com/rhod/info.html#II.2 "The Internet Oracle is the true ancestor of the Stack Exchange network.")** this question outright.

Comment: One question I have. Did it remove the acceptance when I VtD? Monica's answer doesn't show accepted now.

Comment: I tried to accept my own answer and it said I needed to wait 9 hours. It didn't say there was one already accepted.

Answer (score 3):

A woodchuck would chuck a quart of conifer an hour if you gave him a quarter for every cord he chucked.

Comment: For our test purposes, I think this one needs to be voted up.